# AnnotationView Not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom annotation view called "PlaceAnnotationView" as shown below:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class PlaceAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView {

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Then in `viewForAnnotation` I return my custom annotation view as shown:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "PlaceAnnotationView")

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = PlaceAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "PlaceAnnotationView")
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }

        return annotationView 
 }
```

Here is the code to add annotations:

```
private func populateNearByPlaces() {

        var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
        region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = self.selectedCategory
        request.region = region

        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in

            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }

            for item in response.mapItems {

                let annotation = PlaceAnnotation()
                annotation.title = item.name
                annotation.subtitle = "subtitle"
                annotation.mapItem = item

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }


            }

        }


    }
```

Here is the code for PlaceAnnotationView:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class PlaceAnnotationView : MKPinAnnotationView {

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Here is the code for PlaceAnnotation:

import Foundation
import MapKit

```
class PlaceAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {

    var mapItem :MKMapItem!

}
```

But I don't see any of my annotations being displayed on the map. The `viewForAnnotation` is fired multiple times for each of my annotation but does not display anything on the screen.

Comment: how did you add your MKAnnotation? can you show us the code for that ?

Comment: You need to show much more code. Show where you add any annotations to the map view. Show PlaceAnnotationView. Also please note that your implementation of `viewForAnnotation` looks wrong for the case where an annotation view is reused; you are failing to set the annotation view's `annotation`.

Comment: @matt I updated the code. I am not sure if I understand what you mean by the implementation of viewForAnnotation looks wrong.

Comment: I mean you are failing to set the annotation view's `annotation`. You are returning a reused annotation view without configuring it for the new annotation.

Comment: Thanks I added that. Still for some reason I don't see the pin annotations displayed. I added the code to the original question.

Comment: So what's a PlaceAnnotation? You really don't seem to want to show your code here...

Comment: @matt Updated the code again.

Comment: Really? That's all? But then your PlaceAnnotation makes no sense. An MKPointAnnotation has a `coordinate`. That is how the annotation view knows _where_ on the map to show itself. You are never setting the annotation's `coordinate`! Therefore it can never appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code that you have (so reluctantly) chosen to reveal, it seems the problem is that you never set the annotation's `coordinate`. But an annotation's `coordinate` is *crucial*. This is how the annotation tells where it is supposed to be in the world, and how the annotation view associated with this annotation knows where on the map to appear. Therefore the annotation view associated with this annotation does *not* know where on the map to appear. Therefore it *doesn't* appear.

Comment: Thanks! Yikes I forgot to set the coordinates for the annotation :)